# Problem with HDD spindown

Tags: debian, arch-linux, hard-disk, udev, hdparm

I'm trying to spin down my HDD after 10 minutes so I did `hdparm -S 120 /dev/sda` but it doesn't spin down. (I didn't reboot but I also have an udev rule which executes this command)  But when I do `hdparm -y /dev/sda` it works perfectly. And it stays spun down, so I'm sure that the drive isn't accessed.

I'm using Archlinux and have the newest updates installed. I have the same problem on my Banana Pro but it worked before.

It turned out that the HDD I wanted to spin down doesn't support APM and that with my secondary HDD it works perfectly. But I still can't get it to run on my Banana Pro with Bananian installed (Debian Distro). So do you have any idea on why automatic spin down doesn't work there?

ANSWER: The problem disappeared for no reason.

Comment: It's possible (though rare for modern HDDs) that the HDD doesn't support a standby timer. Check with `hdparm -I`.

Comment: Try enabling `/proc/sys/vm/block_dump`, the resulting logs may still reveal something.

Comment: @dirkt Thank you. I'll have a look at it but I don't think that this is the problem because on my other PC (Banana Pro) it worked but now it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @dirk Sadly the drive I have doesnt have standby timer support. BUT the other drive I have does (cause it worked a week before) and there it still doesnt work.